# Array length does not match index length

Tags: pandas, date, time-series

I'm looking to combine a few time series with varying dates into a single dataframe.

Each time series' column names are `date` and `px`

I've created a date index `dates` and tried to combine all the time series by doing:

`dates = pd.date_range('01/01/2017', periods=12, freq='M')`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'date': dates,
   'a': df2['px'],
   'b': df3['px']
   .
   .
   etc
})
```

Expected Output:

```
      date          a           b           c           d           e
2017-01-31    -0.4579         nan           .           .           .
2017-02-28     0.5787         nan           .           .           .
2017-03-31    -2.2319     -1.0244         etc         etc         etc
2017-04-30    -2.0713     -2.1069
2017-05-31        nan      2.0158
2017-06-30        nan      1.0541
2017-07-31        nan      1.8901
2017-08-31        nan         nan
2017-09-30        nan         nan
.
.
etc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
dfs = [df1,df2,df3]
pd.concat([df.set_index('date') for df in dfs], axis=1).reset_index()
```

Comment: This is great! Is it best to rename the columns just using `df.columns` ?

Comment: @J.D.Marlin, it depends... How do you want to name them?

Comment: Probably up to 30 or so. Each invidual time series has `date`, `px`, `px_2`, `px_3`, etc and when concatenating them together I'd like them as `a`,`'a_2`, `a_3`, `b`, `b_2`, `b_3` etc

Comment: can you post an output of `print(concatenated_df.columns.tolist())`?

Answer (score 2):

All the columns of the dataframe have to be of same length and hence you can not create a dataframe from series of varying length. You can use multiple merge in you case with parameter how = 'outer', something like this.

```
df1.merge(df2, on = 'date', how = 'outer').merge(df3, on = 'date', how = 'outer')
```

Since you have not provided snippets of individual series, it's difficult to try the code and show the output here.